# I have been trying to write the Unit test cases in swift for making an API call but not able to figure out how to write

Tags: swift, mvvm, xctest, xctestcase

I have been trying to write Unit test cases in swift for making an API call but being new in this am not able to figure out how do I write the Unit test case for the same. here's my code for which I want to write the unit test case

```
class QuotesModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var quotes = [Quote]()

    @MainActor  
    func fetchData() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://breakingbadapi.com/api/quotes") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            quotes = try JSONDecoder().decode([Quote].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
//        print(quotes)
    }
 
}
```

I have been trying to write the unit testcase for this but am not able to figure out how do I do it. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Break out the decoding into a separate function and write a test for that part. You shouldn't try to unit test URLSession. That way you also get a better separation of logic.

Answer (score 0):

`URLSession.shared` is a singleton. There's nothing wrong with using singletons. But if you use them directly, your dependencies become hard-wired and you give up control. And `URLSession` is an "awkward dependency" that makes testing harder. Let's replace it.

So change your code so that it uses `URLSession.shared` when in production, but something else during testing — something your tests can control. Let's introduce a protocol, as I describe in https://qualitycoding.org/swift-mocking/

```swift
protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    // We will add more here
}
```

Use an extension to make `URLSession` conform to this new protocol:

```
extension URLSession: URLSessionProtocol {}
```

Change your production code to use an instance of this protocol instead of directly calling `URLSession.shared`. But provide `URLSession.shared` as the default value. For example, we can add an argument to your method:

```swift
func fetchData(urlSession: URLSessionProtocol = URLSession.shared) async { … }
```

To make it possible to use `urlSession`, the protocol needs the `URLSession` method you use:

```swift
protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    func data(for request: URLRequest, delegate: URLSessionTaskDelegate?) async throws -> (Data, URLResponse)
}
```

Unfortunately, we can't directly add the `= nil` default value for the `delegate` argument directly in the protocol. The easiest way to resolve this is to pass it explicitly from your calling code, which will now look like

```swift
let (data, _) = try await urlSession.data(from: url, delegate: nil)
```

(We could also add an extension to the protocol.)

Now test code can provide a different implementation which records how it was called. (How many times was it called? Did you use the correct URL?) And it returns canned data controlled by the test.

…All this to say: Don't write code and expect to be able to write microtests for it, as-is. This is hard. Instead, shape your code to make it easy to write microtests.